# Determine cost of items in one dictionary based on prices in another

Tags: python, dictionary

Here I have a program that gives a total price of individual groceries by multiplying price and stock. But what should I use to find the total price of all groceries combined?

```
total = 0
prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple" : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear" : 3
}

stock = {
    "banana" : 9,
    "apple" : 0,
    "orange" : 18,
    "pear" : 22
}

for i in prices:
    print (i.title())
    print ("Price:", prices[i])
    print ("Stock:", stock[i])
    print ("=================")

for key in prices:
    print(key.title() + " Total Price:" , prices[key]*stock[key])
```

Comment: You already have a loop. All you have to do is keep a running total, how do you think you could add such a thing to that loop?

Comment: Hint : may be a variable that can add up the values as you see them

Comment: Can you have a list or dict of groceries and loop through them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing shopping-list total using dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189978/computing-shopping-list-total-using-dictionaries)

Comment: Actually, [Loop through 2 dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19547281) might be better. And then there's [Computing shopping list total using dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29189978)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum(prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices)`

Comment: Typo: drop the 's' at the end of stocks, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the total of all items in stock, you can store the totals data in a structure that will be easy to key off of later, providing ease of manipulation:

```
totals = {k:(stock[k] * prices[k]) for k in prices if k in stock}

In [12]: sum(totals.values())
Out[12]: 129.0
```